# New JSON information being written on top of old info instead of being erased

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

```
    var tempUpdate = setInterval(getJSON, 5000);
    var header = document.querySelector('header');
    var section = document.querySelector('section');
    var requestURL = 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/mykey/41.5456657,-72.6746849';
    function getJSON(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', requestURL);
    request.responseType = 'json';
    request.send();
    request.onload = function() {
    window.superHeroes = request.response;
    populateHeader(superHeroes);
            $.ajaxSetup({
  cache:false
});
    }
    }

    function populateHeader(jsonObj) {
  var myH1 = document.createElement('h1');
  myH1.className = "temp"
  myH1.textContent = roundUp(jsonObj['currently']['apparentTemperature'], 100) + "°";
  header.appendChild(myH1);
  }
```

I thought it had something to do with JSON caching, so I looked around and added that cache:false command, but that didn't do the trick. I tried setting the textContent to " " before writing the JSON info. Nothing worked. It's writing the new information directly on top of the old information so it looks like a big mess of numbers stacked on top of each other.

Comment: You keep creating a new `h1` element and appending it to the `header` element on each call, so what do you expect ? Just create the `h1` element once, outside of `populateHeader` and change its `textContent` inside `populateHeader`.

Comment: $.ajaxSetup wont work with XMLHttpRequest. Use $.ajax instead.

Comment: Thank you DavidDomain. I was unaware that reloading the JSON would also create a new element. I created a div instead and set it to read out whatever the JSON returns.